# how can I specify a list of colors for rectangles using patches.PathPatch?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to make a plot consisting of coloured rectangles, and have been using this example https://matplotlib.org/gallery/misc/histogram_path.html#sphx-glr-gallery-misc-histogram-path-py as a guide:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.path as path

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

data = np.random.randn(1000)
n, bins = np.histogram(data, 50)

# get the corners of the rectangles for the histogram
left = np.array(bins[:-1])
right = np.array(bins[1:])
bottom = np.zeros(len(left))
top = bottom + n

XY = np.array([[left, left, right, right], [bottom, top, top, bottom]]).T

# get the Path object
barpath = path.Path.make_compound_path_from_polys(XY)

# make a patch out of it
patch = patches.PathPatch(barpath)
ax.add_patch(patch)

# update the view limits
ax.set_xlim(left[0], right[-1])
ax.set_ylim(bottom.min(), top.max())

plt.show()
```

I would like a different colour for each rectangle and thought I could do this using a list of floats in cols and setting

```
patch=patches.PathPatch(barpath,fill=True,color=cols
,cmap='CMRmap')
```

But I get "Invalid rgba arg", does this routine only recognize RGB lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `matplotlib.patches.PathPatch` has a single facecolor. It cannot be used to colorize parts of it differently. This is mentioned in [the example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/misc/histogram_path.html#sphx-glr-gallery-misc-histogram-path-py)

> can draw collections of regularly shaped objects with **homogeneous properties** more efficiently with a PathCollection.

So the motivation to use this strategy instead of creating a usual histogram [and colorize its bars](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/hist.html#updating-histogram-colors) is efficiency. A slightly less efficient way of creating a bar plot, but still faster than the usual `bars` is to use a `PolyCollection`.

So let's look at three different solutions below.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(19680801)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.path as path
import matplotlib.collections
import matplotlib.cm

data = np.random.randn(1000)


def compoundpathhist(data, nbins=50):
    n, bins = np.histogram(data, nbins)
    # get the corners of the rectangles for the histogram
    left = np.array(bins[:-1])
    right = np.array(bins[1:])
    bottom = np.zeros(len(left))
    top = bottom + n
    
    
    # we need a (numrects x numsides x 2) numpy array for the path helper
    # function to build a compound path
    XY = np.array([[left, left, right, right], [bottom, top, top, bottom]]).T
    
    # get the Path object
    barpath = path.Path.make_compound_path_from_polys(XY)
    
    # make a patch out of it
    patch = patches.PathPatch(barpath)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.add_patch(patch)
    # update the view limits
    ax.set_xlim(left[0], right[-1])
    ax.set_ylim(bottom.min(), top.max())

    fig.savefig("bartest.png")
        

def polyhist(data, nbins=50, colors=True):
    n, bins = np.histogram(data, nbins)
    # get the corners of the rectangles for the histogram
    left = np.array(bins[:-1])
    right = np.array(bins[1:])
    bottom = np.zeros(len(left))
    top = bottom + n
    # we need a (numrects x numsides x 2) numpy array to be used as 
    # vertices for the PolyCollection
    XY = np.array([[left, left, right, right], [bottom, top, top, bottom]]).T
    
    c=None
    if colors:
        c = matplotlib.cm.RdYlBu(n/n.max())
    pc = matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection(XY, facecolors=c)
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.add_collection(pc)
    # update the view limits
    ax.set_xlim(left[0], right[-1])
    ax.set_ylim(bottom.min(), top.max())
    
    fig.savefig("bartest.png")
        


def hist_c(data, nbins=50, colors=True):

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    n, bins, patches = ax.hist(data, nbins)

    if colors:
        cols = matplotlib.cm.RdYlBu(n/n.max())
        for p,c in zip(patches, cols):
            p.set_facecolor(c)

    # update the view limits
    ax.set_xlim(bins.min(), bins.max())
    ax.set_ylim(n.min(), n.max())

    fig.savefig("bartest.png")

        
compoundpathhist(data, nbins=50)
polyhist(data, nbins=50)
hist_c(data, nbins=50, colors=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

- The first (`compoundpathhist`) is the one from the linked example. It is fast, but cannot show color.
- The second (`polyhist`) doesn't use a single patch, but instead a `PolyCollection`. The `PolyCollection`'s facecolors can be set via a colormap.
- The third (`hist_c`) is the adapted usual solution to colorize individual bars.

Now we can time the three functions. I'm using 90000 data points and 50, 500 and 5000 bins.

[image]

We observe that for a usual number of ~50 bins, there is essentially no difference between those methods. However for larger number of bins, the `hist` method takes significantly longer. Even for 5000 bins, there is almost no difference between the `compoundpathhist` method (which cannot use color) and the `polyhist`, which can use color. This is hence a useful alternative without sacrificing efficiency.
There is by the way almost no difference between using color or not using color in the respective functions.

Comment: Super! thanks - The polyhist function is precisely what I need as my application is not a histogram, but rather a set of xy blocks that are derived from model output.

Comment: Do the blocks have different sizes? If not, there might be even better solutions. (It's always good to ask about the actual problem, i.e. not ask about a histogram, if no histogram is needed.)

Comment: yes you are right, I was trying to make a quick reproducible example before rushing off to a meeting :-( and yes, the blocks do have different sizes.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are following a longer unnecessary route to color each bar differently. Simply use the following (shorter) approach. Using `PathPatch` and `Path` is not at all required. You can remove `edgecolor='black'` if you don't want the black edges.

**Explanation**: Get the `patches` object *directly* from the `plt.hist`. Then, create a list of colors based on the colormap `CMRmap`. Finally loop over the `patches` and set the color of each patch.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

data = np.random.randn(1000)
N, bins, patches = plt.hist(data, bins=50, edgecolor='black')

cm = plt.get_cmap('CMRmap')
for i in range(len(patches)):
    color = cm(1.*i/len(patches))  
    patches[i].set_facecolor(color)
```

[image]

Comment: this is helpful thank you, but I do need to define the rectangle edges as my application is not based on a histogram. I was just working from that as a simple reproducible example.  In my case I want to fill an x-y plot with a list of irregular length blocks. Would you know how I would set the colors within that framework?

Comment: Do you want to loop over all the patches? If yes then you can set similarly to my solution. I am not getting you. Do you want each single patch with a color map as whole?